# How to get access to entire file hierarchy?

Tags: java, filesystems

With the syntax

```
File fs = new File(path);
```

One can get an instance of that path, say any of the drive and from there I can have access of files and directories inside it. But say for instance if I want my program to crawl into all the drives (say C, D, F), what could possibly the path be?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`File.listRoots()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots--) and iterate the array, like

```
for (File fs : File.listRoots()) {
    // ...
}
```